# CSS "not" selector does not work

Tags: css

I can not put two different rule in the "not" selector
Example:

This code works:

```
input:not([type=submit]) {
  // Styling here
}
```

but this code does not work:

```
input:not([type=submit], [type=reset]) {
  // Styling here
}
```

Why the second code does not work?

Answer (score 6):

Your CSS syntax is invalid.

Use 2 `:not` selectors:

```
input:not([type=submit]):not([type=reset]) {
  // Styling here
}
```

Comment: OK, but this becomes a hassle when there are a lot of code.

eg: `input:focus:invalid:not([type=submit]), input:focus:invalid:not([type=reset]), ...`

Comment: @JérémyDupont No, you just do `input:focus:invalid:not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])`